# PHP Session not working on home page

Tags: php, session

So I tried to add sessions in PHP. My website has 2 pages index.php and page.php The script in index.php is

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter']++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
}
echo $_SESSION['counter']."<br>";
?>
<html>
<body>
<a href="page.php">Go to page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and the script in page.php is

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter']++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
}
echo $_SESSION['counter']."<br>";
?>
<html>
<body>
<a href="index.php">Go to index</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When i open index.php, it prints counter as 1. I reload it a couple of times and counter gets incremented nicely. Then, if i go on page.php, it displays the correct value of counter(the one last seen in index.php+1). I reload that page also a couple of times, counter still gets incremented properly. But, if i go on index.php now, it displays counter as 1 where it should have displayed value lats seen in page.php+1

It looks to me like session variables are destroyed then again getting started. I dont want that to happen. Any clue as to how to correct it?? Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: `session_start();` goes on top, then apply the conditional. If not set, echo/do something. Edit: Or, do as @JohnConde says; that's your best bet.

Comment: Get rid of `if(!isset($_SESSION)){`. Just put session_start(); That's all you need.

Comment: You should always call `session_start()` at the top of your page (before any output).

Comment: I removed the `if(!isset($_SESSION)){` line from both pages but it still ain't working...

Comment: Worked fine for me. Old session must still be in memory, try and destroy it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You should [start session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before using `$_SESSION`. Write `session_start();` top of the those pages in which pages you need to use `$_SESSION`. You need to start session both `page.php` & `index.php` page before using `$_SESSION` & no need to use `isset()` to start session. Something like this:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter']++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
}
echo $_SESSION['counter']."<br>";
```

Comment: nope. still ain't working

Comment: Did you change both pages `page.php` & `index.php` ?

Comment: Yes i changed both pages

Comment: Try this
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter']++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
}
echo $_SESSION['counter']."<br>";